# Access property in object

Tags: php, laravel

How do I access the `author` property from this structure?

```
RecordDetails {#461 ▼
  +record: Posts {#481 ▼
    +timestamps: false
    +rules: []
    +table: "blog_posts"
    +attachOne: array:1 [▶]
    +implement: null
    +attributes: array:9 [▼
      "id" => 18
      "title" => "Example Post 18"
      "slug" => "example-post-18"
      "category" => "example-category-2"
      "author" => "example-author-2"
      "date_time" => "2018-02-13 14:42:00"
```

I have tried `$componentObj->record->attributes->author` but that didn't work - `Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$componentObj->record->attributes[author];
```

Answer (score 1):

Asuming the variable that contains the result of eloquest is - $dbResponse.

Solution -

$dbResponse->author;